# Date error displaying

Tags: php, html

Im doing a bit of php. First thing to clarify is that the * is the hidden text I didnt want to show. I was wandering why every time I try and type in a date e.g. 29/11/2013 it would come up on the php page as 0000-00-00. Could someone explain to me where I went wrong and give me a proper explanation on why and how it works, thanks very much.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XYZ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Insert into Database <i>XYZ</i> table <i>addressbook</i></h1>
      <form method="get" action="*********************************************      ">
        <b>ID:</b> <input type="text" name="ID"><br>
     <b>CARNAME:</b> <input type="text" name="CARNAME"><br>
        <b>FUELTYPE:</b> <input type="text" name="FUELTYPE"><br>
        <b>TRANSMISSION:</b> <input type="text" name="TRANSMISSION"><br>
        <b>ENGINESIZE:</b> <input type="text" name="ENGINESIZE"><br>
        <b>DOORS:</b> <input type="text" name="DOORS"><br>
        <b>TOTAL:</b> <input type="text" name="TOTAL"><br>
        <b>AVAILABLE:</b> <input type="text" name="AVAILABLE"><br>
        <b>DATEADDED:</b> <input type="text" name="DATEADDED"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>





<html>
  <head>
    <title>XYZ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Insert into Database <i>XYZ</i> table <i></i></h1>
    <?php
      $link = mysql_connect ("**********", "*********", "*********");
      mysql_select_db ("***********");

      $ID = $_GET["ID"];
      $CARNAME = $_GET["CARNAME"];
      $FUELTYPE = $_GET["FUELTYPE"];
      $TRANSMISSION = $_GET["TRANSMISSION"];
      $ENGINESIZE = $_GET["ENGINESIZE"];
      $DOORS = $_GET["DOORS"];
      $TOTAL = $_GET["TOTAL"];
      $AVAILABLE = $_GET["AVAILABLE"];
      $DATEADDED = $_GET["DATEADDED"];

      $query = "INSERT into CAR values ('$ID', '$CARNAME', '$FUELTYPE', '$TRANSMISSION', '$ENGINESIZE', '$DOORS', '$TOTAL', '$AVAILABLE', '$DATEADDED')";
      $result = mysql_query ($query);

      $query = "SELECT * from CAR";
      $result = mysql_query ($query);

      print "<table>";
      print "<tr>";
      print "<th>ID</th><th>CARNAME</th><th>FUELTYPE</th><th>TRANSMISSION</th><th>ENGINESIZE</th><th>DOORS</th><th>TOTAL</th><th>AVAILABLE</th><th>DATEADDED</th>";
      print "</tr>";
      for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows ($result); $i ++)
      {        
        $row = mysql_fetch_object ($result);
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>$row->ID</td>";
     print "<td>$row->CARNAME</td>";
        print "<td>$row->FUELTYPE</td>";
        print "<td>$row->TRANSMISSION</td>";
        print "<td>$row->ENGINESIZE</td>";
        print "<td>$row->DOORS</td>";
        print "<td>$row->TOTAL</td>";
        print "<td>$row->AVAILABLE</td>";
        print "<td>$row->DATEADDED</td>";
        print "</tr>";
      }
      print "</table>";
      mysql_close ($link);
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql your data should of format yyyyMMdd so you should first convert it before inserting it

```
$DATEADDED = $_GET["DATEADDED"];
```

becomes something like

```
$DATEADDED = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET["DATEADDED"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your date format in your database Y/m/d or if it set to date...  Else change it to varchar (255) to be able to include any format.

Comment: Great advise, thanks for that. Just went into the database and noticed I set it to DATE, changed it and now its working Marinus!